# Clarification of notation for finite-difference equations and applying it to an example

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to apply the notation for finite difference equations in my book to an example.

The following is a finite-difference equation:$$
y_{n+1} = a y_{n}
$$ where $a$ is a constant parameter. The explicit general solution is 
$$
y_{n} = y_{0}a^{n}
$$ 
where $y_0$ is a free constant.

An excerpt from my book:

A $\textit{finite-difference equation}$ is an ordinary difference equation in which the independent variable, $x$, starts from a fixed base point value (such as $0$), in which case it is natural to consider $y$ as a function of the integers: $y: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$). We then use the shorthand notation $y_{n} := y(x + n\delta)$. In this case, we have equations containing the discrete variable $y_{n}$and its various shifts $y_{n-k}, y_{n-k-+1}, \cdots , y_{n+l-1}, \cdots , y_{n+l}$. Thus the canonical form of a difference equation is 
$$
\mathcal{F}(y_{n-k}, y_{n-k+1}, \cdots , y_{n+l - 1}, y_{n+l}; n) = 0, \; \forall n\in \mathbb{Z}
$$

How do I apply this notation to the above example?

In my thought process I am thinking: $x$ is $n$ steps of length $\delta$ from some fixed point $x_0$, i.e., $x = x_0 + n\delta$. Then we consider its various shifts: we go "left" $k$ times of length $\delta$ and "right" $l$ times of length $\delta$. But, I am failing to realize how to write the above example in this sort of notation. How do I write it using the shifts $k$ and $l$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case $\delta=1$, $k=0$ and $l=1$. Your $\mathcal{F}$ is
$$
\mathcal{F}(y_n,y_{n+1};n)=y_{n+1}-ay_n.
$$

Comment: $k = 0$ because we have no $y_{n-1}$, $y_{n-2}$, etc terms in our finite-difference equation right? Similarly, $l = 1$ because our equations only has $y_{n+1}$. Not $y_{n+2}$, $y_{n+3}$ etc. Is $\delta = 1$ by arbitrary choice? Why not $2$? Or $\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: That is exactly right.

Comment: I would say $\delta=1$  is the default value, used when you are dealing with sequences and recursive relations. Say, the Fibonacci sequence is defined by the difference equation $y_{n+2}=y_{n+1}+y_n$ and initial conditions $y_1=1$ and $y_2=1$, etc. Your equation is of order one, and its solutions are geometric sequences with ratio $a$.